# css bootstrap slider menu fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i'm working in this bootstrap carousel, now i have this code working, but i need to fix some issues.

1) make the menu responsive.
2) make the button selected taller than the others.

i tried a lot of thigs but i haven't found the solution yet, so i came here, maybe someone can help me, thank you so much!

This is the image as an example

[image]

the code is in the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(ev){
    $('#custom_carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (evt) {
      $('#custom_carousel .controls li.active').removeClass('active');
      $('#custom_carousel .controls li:eq('+$(evt.relatedTarget).index()+')').addClass('active');
    })
});
```

```css
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
      .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
          width: 100%;
          /*margin: auto;*/
          /*border: 2px solid green;*/
      }
      .carrusel {
          width: 100%;
          height: 40px;
          /*margin: auto;*/
          border: 3px solid red;
          float:right;
          margin: 0px 0px 00px 0px;
          /*background-color: black;*/

      }

      .slide{
        /*border: 2px solid #093845;*/
        width: auto;
      }

      
      /*nav slider*/
      .navi ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
          background-color: #f3f3f3;
          border: 1px solid red;
          height: 50px;
         
      }

      .navi li {
          float: left;
          border: 1px solid red;
          width: 210px;

      }

      .navi li a {
          display: block;
          color: #666;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
      }

      .navi li a:hover:not(.active) {
          background-color: #ddd;
          
      }

      .navi li a.active {
          color: white;
          background-color: #4CAF50;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- This file has been downloaded from Bootsnipp.com. Enjoy! -->
    <title>Tabbed Slider Carousel (inspired by sevenx.de) - Bootsnipp.com</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        
    
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5GEmJ3I7yUU/UdOLNokyFYI/AAAAAAAAABw/RJJLVs9O02I/s1600/carros+de+lujo+%282%29.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5GEmJ3I7yUU/UdOLNokyFYI/AAAAAAAAABw/RJJLVs9O02I/s1600/carros+de+lujo+%282%29.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5GEmJ3I7yUU/UdOLNokyFYI/AAAAAAAAABw/RJJLVs9O02I/s1600/carros+de+lujo+%282%29.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5GEmJ3I7yUU/UdOLNokyFYI/AAAAAAAAABw/RJJLVs9O02I/s1600/carros+de+lujo+%282%29.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5GEmJ3I7yUU/UdOLNokyFYI/AAAAAAAAABw/RJJLVs9O02I/s1600/carros+de+lujo+%282%29.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>                    

    </div>

  </div>
   <!-- Indicators -->      
   <div class="navi">
      <ul class="">      
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="boton active"><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="boton "><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="boton"><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class="boton"><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4" class="boton"><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>  
      </ul>
  </div>




     



</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I know this is probably a little more than you asked for but I figured I would help out and make this fully responsive for you.  I left in the carousel captions and headings just in case you wanted to use them for future use but if not you can just take them out.  So what I like to do with the bootstrap carousels is give the carousel item a padding-bottom of a percentage and then mess with this percentage until you get your desired height.  Then I like to just give each item a background image of the image that you want to put in your carousel because not all images have the same aspect ratio and you will run into problems with images being skewed otherwise.  If you don't want to use the background image method you can just use your method but I figured I would throw this in there because it works best for responsive design.  So i give each carousel item a class eg. first-item, second item, third-item and so on and then give then all a backgorund image of whatever your slide image was.  Then we will just put your nav underneath the carousel and your all set.  Also you will want to add `data-interval="false"` to your #myCarousel div because when you click on one of the slides it will start to cycle though the slides and your active tabs will still be on the one that you clicked on. Removing active classes while the carousel is in auto interval is a whole different set of jquery markup.  Also I have set your carousel nav buttons to 20% because there are 5 of them.  If you want them to be a different percentages then add a media query to make them a bigger size like and you will also have to change the carousel-nav height and maybe not have the active button apear bigger as well:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .carousel-nav li{width: 100%;)
}
```

Here is a working Fiddle demo [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/x7vcvgms/)

So here is the markup:

Html:

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active first-item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <p class="carousel-heading">Example Heading 1</p>
          <p class="carousel-description">Example of a Carousel Description</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Carousel Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item second-item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <p class="carousel-heading">Example Heading 2</p>
          <p class="carousel-description">Example of a Carousel Description</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Carousel Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item third-item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <p class="carousel-heading">Example Heading 3</p>
          <p class="carousel-description">Example of a Carousel Description</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Carousel Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item fourth-item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <p class="carousel-heading">Example Heading 4</p>
          <p class="carousel-description">Example of a Carousel Description</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Carousel Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item fifth-item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <p class="carousel-heading">Example Heading 5</p>
          <p class="carousel-description">Example of a Carousel Description</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Carousel Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->


<ul class="carousel-nav">
  <li class="active" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"><button>Button 1</button></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><button>Button 2</button></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><button>Button 3</button></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"><button>Button 4</button></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"><button>Button 5</button></li>
</ul>
```

The Css:

```
#myCarousel .item{
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 250px;
}
#myCarousel .first-item{
  background-image: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5GEmJ3I7yUU/UdOLNokyFYI/AAAAAAAAABw/RJJLVs9O02I/s1600/carros+de+lujo+%282%29.jpg');
}
#myCarousel .second-item{
  background-image: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5GEmJ3I7yUU/UdOLNokyFYI/AAAAAAAAABw/RJJLVs9O02I/s1600/carros+de+lujo+%282%29.jpg');
}
#myCarousel .third-item{
  background-image: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5GEmJ3I7yUU/UdOLNokyFYI/AAAAAAAAABw/RJJLVs9O02I/s1600/carros+de+lujo+%282%29.jpg');
}
#myCarousel .fourth-item{
  background-image: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5GEmJ3I7yUU/UdOLNokyFYI/AAAAAAAAABw/RJJLVs9O02I/s1600/carros+de+lujo+%282%29.jpg');
}
#myCarousel .fifth-item{
  background-image: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-5GEmJ3I7yUU/UdOLNokyFYI/AAAAAAAAABw/RJJLVs9O02I/s1600/carros+de+lujo+%282%29.jpg');
}
#myCarousel .carousel-heading{font-size: 40px;}

.carousel-nav{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
.carousel-nav li{
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
.carousel-nav li button,.carousel-nav li button:focus{
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  outline: 0;
}
.carousel-nav li.active button, .carousel-nav.active li button:focus{
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  outline: 0;
}
/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    #myCarousel .carousel-heading{font-size: 18px;}
    #myCarousel .carousel-description{font-size: 12px;}
    #myCarousel .btn-primary{font-size: 14px;}
}
```

And your jquery:

Note: this may require you to use a newer version of jquery so you may want to add this instead of 1.11  in you head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then the jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.carousel-nav button', function() {
    $('.carousel-nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
});
```

Comment: Wow!!!!... This is incredible, i know understand that my knowledge are very limited, i don't even can think the way you solve this... simple incredible!, thank you so much, for taking the time to solve and explain how you solve this problem that i had, agan thank you again, i really glad, i'll be checking each line of the code yo write, and try the understand!!

Comment: No problem at all if you have any questions feel free to comment me and I will get back with you as soon as possible.  Also if this answers the question consider clicking the check mark next to the answer when you get everything up and running.  Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Change height to auto in the class ".navi ul" so it will be like

```
.navi ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: auto;         
}
```

Change width of buttons to 20% in ".navi li" class so it will be like

```
.navi li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 20%;
}
```

and add one more class for selected button

```
.navi li.active a {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 11%;
  margin: -15px 0 0 -2px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 19%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First important thing to note is that, the JavaScript you mentioned doesn't work as per your markup. Specifically, your active classes are not dynamically changing when the slides move. I have modified the JS code to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function(ev){
    $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (evt) {
      $('.navi li.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.navi li:eq('+$(evt.relatedTarget).index()+')').addClass('active');
    })
});
```

Also there is a small mistake on your CSS. The `active` class is applied on the `<li>` tag and not the `<a>`, so the active code should be changed to

```
  .navi li.active {
      background: blue;
      color: white;
  }
```

and NOT `.navi li a.active`.

And to scale the buttons when active, you can make use of the `transform: scale()`. Like so

```
  .navi li.active {
      background: blue;
      color: white;
      -ms-transform: scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); /* Safari */
      transform: scale(1.1);
  }
```